# Type conversion with Boost Generic Image Library

Tags: image-processing, boost, boost-gil

I currently have an image of the type `boost::gil::rgb8c_view_t`. I need to pass it to a function with this prototype:

```
void function(const boost::gil::rgb8c_view_t& input, const int index, const boost::gil::rgb8c_view_t::view_t &output)
```

I have created an output image by using the following syntax:

```
boost::gil::rgb8c_view_t::view_t output(input._dynamic_cast<boost::gil::rgb8c_view_t::view_t>());
```

At this point, the compiler accepts the image `output` as input for the function. However, I need the image back to the `boost::gil::rgb8c_view_t` type. The question is:

- Is it a correct way to allocate the image `output`?
- How do I transform it back to the type `boost::gil::rgb8c_view_t`?

Thank you in advance,
Néstor

Comment: Are you sure that the function prototype is correct? The 'c' in rgb8c_view_t is noting a immutable view on the image. This would be a problem for an output view.

Comment: And with your second code fragment you create no image at all. Have you tried to follow the GIL tutorial at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/gil/doc/html/giltutorial.html?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly (see comments above), but to create an output image with the same size as your input image, you could use a call like the following:

```
boost::gil::rgb8_image_t output_image(input.dimensions());
```

And get a mutable view like this:

```
boost::gil::rgb8_view_t boost::gil::view(output_image);
```

Of course you can also get a constant/immutable view like this:

```
boost::gil::rgb8c_view_t boost::gil::const_view(output_image);
```